# videojs: change title attribute after play

Tags: jquery, attributes, html5-video, title, video.js

I have a HTML5 Video with video.js. I´d like to change the title attribute after starting the video.
My code is:

```
<video id="vidid14" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="554" height="312" controls  poster="Picture_copyright_John_Doe.jpg" title="©John Doe" preload="none">
```

and

```
$(".video-js").each(function (videoIndex) {
var videoId = $(this).attr("id");
videojs(videoId).ready(function(){
this.on("play", function(e) {
this.attr('title', 'your new title'); }); });  });
```

But I get the error message: "VIDEOJS: ERROR: TypeError: this.attr is not a function".

Nothing else worked for me. Is there a solution to change the code?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here in your example `this` is reference of player. As title is not there is `Player` it's firing error.

You can use any of the following as per your need to update title.

`$('#vidid14').attr('title','New Tile');`

or

`$('#vidid14_html5_api').attr('title','New Tile');`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was it:

    $('#' + videoId + '_html5_api').attr('title','new title'); 
changes the title of the video.

    $('#' + videoId ).attr('title','new title'); 
changes the title of the scrubber bar.